# javascript - different result based on where function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to determine the amount of left margin a bootstrap container has, both on page load and on resize of the browser.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var margin = parseInt($('.container').first().css('margin-left'), 10);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var margin = parseInt($('.container').first().css('margin-left'), 10);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 main">
            <div class="content text-center">
                <h1>MAIN CONTENT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
            <div class="content text-center">
                <h1>SIDEBAR</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when this runs on page load, the margin value is about 10px greater than it is on window resize.

Example: I load the page and the margin variable evaluates to 233. When I resize, it immediately evaluates to 225, no matter which directing I am resizing. Any idea the cause of this when the javascript being executed is identical in both cases?

Comment: Hi! Any way we can see this live, or in a codepen? As it is now, it's pretty hard to figure out what might be going on...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your first call wait for the page to be loaded and the second one is directly evaluated.

Take a look at this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrOWoZ?editors=0011

When you wrap a function with jQuery like this `$( function(){ /* code */ } )`

JQuery wait for the document to be ready. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

`$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});`

When you bind directly the event it won't wait for the document to be ready.

I hope this help !

Comment: thank you, looks like the margins are identical when calling document.ready and on resize in your example. any idea what could be going on differently in mine?

Comment: I think that you need to wrap the event handler in `$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});` 

In other word, wait for the page to be loaded with document.ready on window.onload